# On pgAdmin 4, how to basically copy the content of one or two cells?

Tags: pgadmin

I decided to go on pgAdmin 4 instead of the 3 (I'm on Windows 7).
It seems that this software if somehow still in a alpha state...

I would like to only get the content of one cell. So I select this cell and tap Ctrl+C.

But it seems NOT to copy the content to the clipboard (the previous clipboard content stays when I paste...).

I notice that the copy button in the topbar stays disabled...

On the [pgAdmin 4 GUI Tool page](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs4/1.x/query_tool.html), it seems the only proposed way to copy is to click on this button :

> Click the Copy icon to copy the currently selected row.

Do anybody has a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 7):

This is for pgAdmin 4   /  Version 2.0

Hit F8 (download as CSV) , or click the rightmost button [image]

After that, save the Data Output as a csv file (of your choice)[image]

Comment: As of now, this button (or F8) saves the file as CSV but its content is XML...

Answer (score 6):

OK I've found.

You have to double click on the cell, then a popup pops up, with the cell content selected, and then you can use ctrl+c...

Answer (score 2):

There is a green row with a floppy disk that saves the result of your query.

[image: Save query]

Comment: The OP wants to copy the content of one cell.

Comment: OP asked about pgadmin4, not 3. Version 4 has a button to download the results as CSV, but only after executing.

Answer (score 1):

For integer or double columns, the 'pop-up' mentioned by @user3550873 doesn't appear so you cannot copy from there, but there is a workaround :

**Drag and Drop works !**

So, you can drag-and-drop the value you want to the query text field, then copy it anywhere from there.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with some limit:

1. click on the target cell
2. `ctrl + c`

It works when the window can show all the columns. If you scroll from left to right for the result(if the result has many columns), it doesn't work. Maybe it's a bug.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In PgAdmin 4 there is the configuration for show max characters per column.
Go to file > options > query tool, update the "max. characters per column" as per your limit, I have set as 10000.

[image]

Comment: the problem is that I can see a lot of characters, much more than copied using the Ctrl+C key combination. I have to use the @user3550873 solution to get the whole cell saved from the query